# Задать шаг в цикле for Pascal

Tags: pascal, for

Нужно создать цикл **for**, который выводит на экран числа от **0,5** до **1,5** с шагом **0,25** в Pascal

Comment: Вы ведь даже не пытались открыть учебник или хотя бы погуглить самостоятельно такую тривиальную задачу, не так ли?

Comment: `for i := 2 to 6 do  Writeln(i/4);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Счетчик цикла for или параметр цикла — это обычная переменная, которая
>   может быть только **порядкового (целочисленного, символьного,
>   логического) или перечислимого типа**.
>
> При прямом направлении цикла счетчик в каждой итерации увеличивается
>   на единицу, при обратном направлении — уменьшается на единицу.

Для дробных шагов можно воспользоваться циклом `while`:

```
a := 0.5;
while a <= 1.5  do
begin
  writeln(a);
  a := a + 0.25;
end;
```

Comment: Да, с while проще. Но у меня задание сделать это с for.
    for i:=4 to 12 do
  if i mod 2=0 then
    begin
      h:=i*0.125;
      writeln(h:3:2);
    end;
Это конечно не совсем то что надо, но работает.